# $response->redirect not works

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I have an IVR that plays some audios for the user and then I need to redirect to another php file. The strange thing is that this redirect does not work.

NOTE 1: the redirect that does not work is the last one ($response->redirect("./chooseLicense.php?rs=$rs"))

NOTE 2: if I put it in if(!is_object($rs)) it works perfectly.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Snippet of my code:

```
$rs = json_decode(Curl::post(baseUrl . "users/auth/", $cpfOrCnpj, $password));

// logText('rs in login', $rs);

if(!is_object($rs)) {
    $gather->play("https://digital-lock-api.azurewebsites.net/ura-hmg/assets/audios/licenseNotFound.mp3");
}

if($rs->licenses === []) {
    $gather->play("https://digital-lock-api.azurewebsites.net/ura-hmg/assets/audios/licenseNotFound.mp3");
}

if(count($rs->licenses) == 1) {
    $licenseId = $rs->licenses[0]->id;
    $isBlocked = $rs->licenses[0]->blocked;
    $token = $rs->auth->token;
    $response->redirect("./waitForFlip.php?licenseId=$licenseId&isBlocked=$isBlocked&token=$token");
}

if(count($rs->licenses) > 1) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach($rs->licenses as $license) {
        $count++;
        $gather->play("https://digital-lock-api.azurewebsites.net/ura-hmg/assets/audios/chooseLicense$count.mp3");
        $gather->play($license->nicknameAudioUrl);
    } 

    $rs = json_encode($rs);

    logText("rs encode", $rs);

    $response->redirect("./chooseLicense.php?rs=$rs");
}
```

Comment: So, everything within `if(count($rs->licenses) > 1)` does not execute because `$rs` is not an object or the value of `count($rs->licenses)` is not > 1? Or the `$response->redirect` in question is being executed and simply not performing as expected?

Comment: Also, you seem to be redefining `$rs` for purposes of encoding. Do you do this elsewhere, if so can you reproduce this problem there as well? Do a `var_dump( $rs )` twice, one before the `json_encode` and one immediately after and post the results please. If what I suspect is happening this might be the issue and can be remedied by modifying `json_encode` with the appropriate flags in the optional second parameter.

Comment: It goes inside the if(count($rs->licenses > 1)), and runs all the commands, but when it reaches the redirect passing the encoded $rs inside the url it gets an error. But if I pass it without the rs, it works.

Comment: I am at a loss for words considering I already used the magic ones. Once more, you MUST do a `var_dump( $rs )` twice, one before the `json_encode` and one immediately after and post the results. Depending on the needs of those who would benefit from this project you have going on, "whenever" or immediately.

Comment: I'd add some stricter typing or type testing so that $rs can only be of a certain type at a certain time. To help out with that, I recommend step-through debugging with Xdebug to help you determine what $rs is and is initialised with at various points in the flow of the code. Here's a set up short tutorial, if you're interested: https://matthewsetter.com/setup-step-debugging-php-xdebug3-docker/